# .NET Core 3.1 Unable to run executable program from PHP shell_exec()

Tags: c#, php, linux, .net-core

I've built my program into a release executable file and now I'm trying to execute it through PHP `shell_exec()` function as below:

```
$result = shell_exec("./myprogram 2>&1");
```

But it always throwing `Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E` error.

Even I have allocated 16G RAM for this server. It can run **successfully** if been executed directly from **internal bash** instead of from PHP `shell_exec()`. What's wrong here?

Comment: Maybe `PATH` setting?

Comment: What `PATH` do you mean?

Comment: 1) the error code indicates that the common language runtime cannot allocate enough memory, maybe there is a limit for shell_exec?. dotnetcore can quite eat memory. did 2) you try to directly shell_execute dotnet? like `dotnet <xxx>.dll`

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer Yes, I did `dotnet --version` with `shell_exec()`. It throws same result.

Comment: which cpu architecture are you running dotnet / php on ? does dotnet work when executed directly? can you post the PHP_INT_SIZE constant? is it 4 or 8?

Comment: It's x64. Yes, it works when being executed directly from command line. It's just give an error when being run from `shell_exec()`. I just increased memory_limit in php.ini configuration into 2G but still not working.

Comment: Got any working solutions?